# C# Firebase User Authenicatoin

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I need to create a .NET (C#) application that allows users to mass upload some data to their specific account.

Obviously I don't want to include the Firebase Secret in this .NET application because that would risk exposing the entire db.

Whats the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should indeed not include a token generating ability into code that you ship to your users, since that means you're exposing your Firebase's secret in client-side code.

In this case you'll have to find some way to mint and distribute custom JWT tokens to your users. Typically this means that you'll run your own server that uses one of [Firebase's helper library to generate tokens](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/custom.html#section-rest-token-helper-libraries).

But any other mechanism (e.g. emailing them manually) will work equally well.

Your users app can then pass this token to the [REST API in its `auth` parameter](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/user-auth.html#section-authenticating-requests).

Comment: What I dont understand about the JWT token is how to generate a token for a specific user only.  Would I pass in the username/password to a REST API (for example) and authenticate, if everything is OK, generate a JWT Token with a UID as their login data?

Comment: You determine exactly what goes into the token when you generate it. You would pass this token **to** the REST API. Since you use your Firebase's secret to encrypt the token, Firebase can be certain that the values are yours by decrypting it with the same secret.

Comment: Thank you.  This explains what I need to accomplish.